# How to Retrieve Values from list by comparing it to next and previous values?

Tags: python, list, filter, compare

I've been trying fo several hours on several days to find a solution, but I can't succeed - I don't know what, but I'm missing something...

Need help or suggestions :-D

Here is what I wanna do:

I have two lists:

```
v = [1, 3, 25, 67, 69, 72, 85, 120, 125, 130]
d = [2, 22, 42, 2, 3, 13, 35, 5, 5]
```

v is a set of values and d is a calculation of its intervals

I'd like to filter v in order to retrieve only the vaues which are distant from less than, say, 5.

That would make vf (v filtered):

```
 vf = [1, 3, 67, 69, 72, 120, 125, 130]
```

What I've managed to do so far:

```
for i in range(len(v)-1) :
...     if v[i] - v[i-1] <= 5 or v[i+1] - v[i] <= 5 :
...             df.append(v[i])

vf
[1, 3, 67, 69, 72, 120, 125]
```

I'm missing the last value...

But if I say:

```
for i in range(len(v)) :
...     if v[i] - v[i-1] <= 5 or v[i+1] - v[i] <= 5 :
...             df.append(v[i])
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
IndexError : list index out of range
```

Thanks beforehand for any suggestion you may have :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
v = [1, 3, 25, 67, 69, 72, 85, 120, 125, 130]
d = [2, 22, 42, 2, 3, 13, 35, 5, 5]
vf = []
for i in range(len(v)) :

    if (i > 0 and (v[i] - v[i-1] <= 5)) or ( (i < len(v) - 1) and (v[i+1] - v[i] <= 5)) :
        vf.append(v[i])
print vf
```

Comment: Waww that was simple! Works real nice! I also tried it with v [1] == 22 and vf actually get rid of v [0] (difference > 5) which is exactly what I wanted, many thanks ! ;-) @kshitij-mittal

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm following exactly what result you want. I have assumed you want to keep v[k] if v[k]-v[k-1] <= 5, and also keep the first element v[0] for which this comparison is not possible. So here is the pythonic way to do that:

```
v = [1, 3, 25, 67, 69, 72, 85, 120, 125, 130]
vo = [1] + v[:-1]
# thus: vo = [1, 1, 3, 25, 67, 69, 72, 85, 120, 125]

vf = [x for (x,y) in map(None,v,vo) if x-y <= 5]
print vf
```

which produces: [1, 3, 69, 72, 125, 130]

This uses list comprehensions and map as follows: v is your original list of numbers. vo is a list of the same length as v but offset, to facilitate this comparison. This saves the trouble of separately computing d.

Now vf is constructed with a list comprehension as follows: vf will contain the element x where x is chosen from the tuple (x,y) which is taken, in an iterated fashion, from the tuples formed by elements taken from v and vo, provided that x-y is less than or equal to 5; otherwise x is not added to the vf. See detailed example below.

What map is doing here is creating the list of tuples (x,y) from v and vo. Normally, map is used to map a function onto a list of arguments (to apply a function to lists of arguments). In this case, by using None as the function, we are just creating a list of tuples from v and vo like this:
[(v[0],vo[0]), (v[1],vo[1]), ... ].

In the list comprehension we are then doing this:

First, (x,y) = (v[0],vo[0]) = (1,1). Since x-y = 0 (<=5) then x=1 is included in vf.

Second,(x,y) = (v[1],vo[1]) = (3,1). Since x-y = 2 (<=5) then x=3 is included in vf.

Third,(x,y) = (v[2],vo[2]) = (25,3). Since x-y = 22 (>5) then x=25 is NOT included in vf.

And so on. You'll have to adjust this if I have misunderstood the intended result but this should give an idea of how to use list comprehensions and map to achieve the desired result in two lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll have to adapt and to work it a bit for a good understanding ^^. Actually, the first value is supposed to be deleted if it's difference with the second one is > to 5

Comment: So keep v[k] if v[k+1]-v[k] <= 5? In that case you will never keep the last value in v?

Comment: It may actually happen and it was exactly my problem of being out of v range : the idea is to retrieve any value from v if they are distant <= 5 with either the previous or the next ones. Thus if v [1] - v [0] > 5 AND v [len (v)] - v [len (v) - 1] > 5, both shouldn't be retrieved in vf. --- Sorry if I was not clear in my first post :-)

Comment: Ok, it sounds like you are happy with the for-loop solution.

Comment: Thks for the effort and explanations anyway :-)